# Scalable Image for Body Background in HTML

Tags: html, css

How do I properly set the body background image in HTML to be scaleable?
    I am working on a Chrome extension, so no need to worry about Mobile devices(?) The current HTML page is very simple, I just need it to display an image (will eventually be display random images from a folder, but for now a hard-coded image will suffice). How do I make the image be scaleable when using chrome on different devices with different screen sizes (i.e tablet, laptop, external display for computer) and retain image quality?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> New Tab </title>
    </head>
    <style>
    body {
        background-image:url('indexImage.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
    </style>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'scalable'?

Comment: Absolutely, @WaisKamal. For example, What I mean by scaleable is that if the user open the extension on a smaller or larger screen than the originally supplied image, how could we ensure that the image quality is preserved, as well as that the entire image still fits in the browser window.

Comment: You can use an image layer instead of a background for better manipulation. Just set the `z-index` property of the layer to the lowest and set the CSS to `width: 100%; height: auto`.

Comment: You have `background-size:cover` — How does that differ from what you want?

Comment: if it is to show a single image at once , take a look at srcset in this document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img , https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/ and just size it via css

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to try `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: cover;`.

Answer (score 0):

When i've had to do this in the past I ran into some other considerations. So yes, you can scale it to fill, sure.  But you have to think about the image content itself and how it looks if you STRETCH it.  If its an abstract image it may be fine to stretch, otherwise it might not work out good.

If you don't care about the image distortion you can set HTML and BODY height to 100% and then set the CSS background-size to 100% auto [like this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euu29qrz/).

```
html, body { 
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%; 
}

body {
        background-image:url('http://columbiascbestnewhomes.com/images/brunson-plan.jpg');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:100% 100%;
        background-position: center;
}
```

If it DOES matter that the image not be stretched I would use CSS media queries to have an image for each device or screen type, based on the detected screen width.  Then set the image dynamically and use the background-size CSS I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size` in your style and set values in percent.
like this:

```
<style>
    body {
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%;             
        background-image:url('aa.gif');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 80% 80%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for my login page to my site.  Below is a brief rundown of what I did.  Let know know if it helps.

I found that it flowed a bit better to use an empty div instead of doing the body.

```
@{
   Random random = new Random();
   int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 5);
   string background = "Images/bg-" + randomNumber + ".jpeg";
}


<div id="background" style="background-image: url('@background');"></div>
```

css:

```
html{
   height:100%
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
body{
   min-height:100%
   margin:0;
}
#background{
   background-color:#1f212e; 
   background-position:center; 
   background-size:cover;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
}
```